# How to make verticle line in HTML without CSS?

Tags: html

I wanted to make a verticle line in HTML.
CSS, yes I tried its good but not that. I tried this too

```
<hr size="100%" width="20px">
```

But I wasn't able to write anything beside it...
Please HELP...

Thank you...

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? Writing something "beside" an element with 100% width sounds strange

Comment: Give us a reason why you don't want/can't use CSS, because CSS is what you _should_ use to style HTML elements.

Answer (score -2):

```
<hr>
```

**thats it**
just an hr tag and if wana add some colors then

```
<hr color=#f00>
```

and you can also increase widht and height too or even decrease...

Comment: This will produce a __h__ orizontal line, not a vertical one.